# Access encore-js-File outside of encore (legacy app)

Tags: webpack-4, symfony-3.4, webpack-encore, ecma

In one of my projects, I'm going to exchange the js files step by step. One of my files (hta.js) contains this:

```
export function likeUnlikePost(element, $tag, $companyId) {
    var elementId = element.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    var action = $('#heart-button-' + elementId).attr('action');
    if (action == null) {
        action = $('#love-heart-button-' + elementId).attr('action');
    }
    $.post('/posts/ajax/edit/like/' + elementId, {
        action: action,
        tag: $tag,
        companyId: $companyId,
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            var response = data[elementId];
            if (response == 'unliked') {
                $('#heart-button-span-' + elementId)
                    .removeClass('htaRed').addClass('htaGrey');
                $('#r-heart-button-span-' + elementId)
                    .removeClass('htaRed').addClass('htaGrey');
                $('#r-heart-button-' + elementId).attr('action', 'like');
                $('#heart-button-' + elementId).attr('action', 'like');
            } else if (response == 'liked') {
                $('#heart-button-span-' + elementId)
                    .removeClass('htaGrey').addClass('htaRed');
                $('#r-heart-button-span-' + elementId)
                    .removeClass('htaGrey').addClass('htaRed');
                $('#r-heart-button-' + elementId).attr('action', 'unlike');
                $('#heart-button-' + elementId).attr('action', 'unlike');
            }
            $('#heart-likes-' + elementId)
                .html(data['count']);
            $('#r-heart-likes-' + elementId)
                .html(data['count']);
            $('#div-loved-posts')
                .html(data['lovedPostsHtml'])
                .foundation();
        })
        .fail(function (data) {

        });
}
```

I would like to access this function on two sides in my project. I tried this in webpack.config.js :

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('web/assets/')
    .setPublicPath('/assets')
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('../assets')
    .addEntry('hta', './app/Resources/js/hta.js')
    .addEntry('app', './app/Resources/js/app.js')
    .autoProvideVariables({
        'hta': 'hta',
        'global.hta':'hta',
    })

    .enableSassLoader()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .configureFilenames({
        js: 'js/[name].js',
        css: 'css/[name].css',
        images: 'images/[name].[ext]',
        // images: 'images/[path]/[name].[ext]',
        fonts: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'
    })
;    
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

But, when I try to access this function via

```
document.hta.likeUnlikePost($element, '');
```

I just get an error:

```
TypeError: document.hta is undefined
```

I thought I tried like in this example: [enter link description here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/legacy-apps.html)

But I can't get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 possibilities:
1/ use export like you do. So remove the file from webpack and call import {} from 'path to your file's. Here app/Resources/assets/hta.js 
2/ use webpack remove export function and declare your function in a let now I think you can call directly your function

In two cases don't omit args.

Bye

Answer (score 1):

you must import your function before call them.

Hope that help you.